# In a vscode extension is there a way to programatically Invoke "repl.action.copyall" through vscode.commands.executeCommand(...)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

In short, Im looking for a way to capture the text content of the debug console inside a vscode extension. The following code snippet does pretty much exactly what I want only for the Terminal instead of the debug console. You can also right click in the console and select -> copy all. In the end I wont be pasting it to a new code window but pushing it to an endpoint to automate test reporting.

```
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.selectAll').then(() => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.copySelection').then(() => {
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.clearSelection').then(() => {
                vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile').then(() => {
                    vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardPasteAction');
                });
            });
        }); 
    });
```

I have tried this but I get an error in the console.log

```
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('repl.action.copyall').then(() => {
        vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile').then(() => {
            vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardPasteAction');
        });
    });
```

> ***rejected promise not handled within 1 second: Error: command 'repl.action.copyall' not found
> extensionHostProcess.js:1048
> stack trace: Error: command 'repl.action.copyall' not found
> at u._tryExecuteCommand (file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4213:713)
> at file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.js:4213:594***

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

don't do callback hell with Promises

Just return a new Promise in the `then()` handler

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.selectAll')
    .then(() => vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.copySelection'))         
    .then(() => vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.terminal.clearSelection'))
    .then(() => vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.files.newUntitledFile'))
    .then(() => vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.clipboardPasteAction'))
```

Comment: Better yet, use `await vscode.commands.executeCommand(); await vscode.commands.executeCommand();` etc